# How can I migrate this question?

Tags: support, migration

I think [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/364394/how-to-reverse-default-reverse-chronological-ordering-of-archive-pages) that I asked ("**How to reverse default [reverse-chronological] ordering of archive pages?**") would be better asked on Superuser, with the words "**Wordpress/Astra**:" prepended to the title. Please can somebody tell me how to migrate it, or migrate it for me if only a moderator can do that. Many thanks!

Comment: I would note that what you're asking for in the Q is how WP already works out of the box. You should contact Astra dev support for help with bugs in the Astra theme

Answer (score 1):

**I don't believe the question is related in any way to the SuperUser stack**. *Super User isn't a stack for developer/programming questions. It's for power users*.

If people voted to close the question with the migration clause, or a moderator did it, I believe it would either be migrated back here, or closed outright. That doesn't mean it's on topic here, just that they're trying to be helpful.

For an authorative answer on wether the Q is on topic at SuperUser, you'd need to either ask on their meta site, or succesfully migrate the Q there without it being closed.

*Remember, people on Stack Exchange aren't employees, they're volunteers and users. Nobody here gets paid, and we don't know all the ins and outs of other stacks.*

**As for the Q:**

The problem seems to be that the question is difficult to understand, and looks like you're asking for support for a bug in the Astra themes archive ordering. I've made adjustments to try and make it easier to understand, and make it harder to misinterpret

Comment: So asking how to achieve something is off-topic but knowing what tool to use and asking how to use that tool to achieve it is on-topic? On-topic where? I'll ask it where it's on-topic.

Comment: No, that's a mischaracterisation of what I said. You have a question about a 3rd party theme, that's offtopic. It doesn't matter what you're asking about that theme, or if it's a great or an awful question, that subject is not in this stacks scope, it's offtopic, this isn't the place to ask. Super User is not the the place to ask either. **The best place to ask is the theme vendor**,  afterall it's a premium theme, people trying to answer your question need to pay money to even begin to debug your problem

Comment: It's not about the theme. I mentioned the theme for background. Wordpress is written in PHP. It's about WP and therefore PHP. A bit of PHP in a child theme will override any theme. Astra is not a premium theme - a paid-for "Pro" version exists, but I am using the free version. So there is no "theme vendor" relevant to my question who can be asked anything. I posted the question to Superuser, but they migrated it back here, "because it can be answered on WordPress Development Stack Exchange" (their words). Clearly the right hand of the company doesn't know what the left hand is doing.

Comment: The people who wrote Astra are the theme vendor, wether it's paid for or not doesn't change that. Aside from the 3 official support routes, if they're on .org they must provide support, it's the price they pay .org for hosting: https://wordpress.org/support/theme/astra/

Comment: As for the right hand of the company, i'm not an employee, neither are the people at superuser **we're all volunteers**. SuperUser users won't be intimiately familiar with WPSE's scope, just that it has WP in the name, they were just trying to be helpful, I did say they'd migrate it back. And if it were a generic PHP question, then stackoverflow would be the stack for it. WPSE is not the place to ask though, the vendor of the theme Astra, its makers, are where you need to go, and they've provided a FB group, paid support, docs, and a .org support forum

Comment: @ruffle I've gone back to the original question, and believe the problem is that it was very, **very** difficult to understand, and found an alternative interpretation. Your question reads as: "In my archive posts are ordered by their post ID and i want them ordered chronologically", but now I suspect you actually meant "How do I reverse the numbering of the pagination". Is this the case? Because that question would be on topic

Comment: I've closed the migrated Q as a duplicate, reopened the original, and tried to edit it to make it more obvious that you're actually asking about the pagination numbers, not a bug in Astra. I think the root of the problem is that the Q was just really difficult to understand, and that the Q title made no mention of what you wanted